# how to remove folder name from url in localhost using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to remove folder name from url in localhost using codeigniter ?
Hello 
I am using codeigniter franework for my project. i am saving all my project data in "opt/lampp/htdocs/myprjectfolder" ok. now its working using url "localhost/myprjectfolder"
Now i want to remove that foldername i.e.myprjectfolder from url like "localhost/" can it directly open my website pages(controller)(i.e.myprjectfolder) ? what to do with config.php or route.php file ?please give some time and solution
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

that is not codeigniter config
if we ignoring replace project folder with htdocs
your best solution is using [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

Comment: thnk's Mohamad i am using virtual host now ie my site is running like when i type on url http://somesite.com/ i get display my home page proper But when i am click contact page in my website it cannot find that page and url changed as http://somesite.com/pages/contact but page data cannot disply.please give some time for me

Comment: your problem is`t clear to me dude, 'http://somesite.com/pages/contact' is you content address but it does`t show anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Put all your files out side the folder, directly in htdocs folder(NOT RECOMMENDED).

OR

You can convert localhost to virtual domain names

Ref:

```
     http://drupal.org/node/1152594
     http://www.learnbycode.com/content/how-assign-virtual-local-domain-name-your-localhost
     http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name
```

Comment: You will also need to change the base URL in your config.php I agree though I would not recommend this.

Comment: but it will be very tedious means if i have multiple project folder then it should be messy that all folders are under the htdocs

Comment: Yeah...That is the reason why i said NOT RECOMMENDED, You can convert localhost to virtual domains

Comment: ok jeffrey i do that also but it cannot work like when i type http://localhost/ it goes direct to xampp home page

Comment: ok prashant now please help me little how to convert localhost to virtual domains

Comment: @Sushil : please check the links in my answer

Answer (score 0):

download EasyPHP and set virtual domain, easy way

http://www.easyphp.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove folder name in in `config/routes.php` file:

```
$route['folder/product/(:any)'] = "product/(:any)";
```